# Push notification not working in Angular 7 app with firebase

Tags: firebase, push-notification, angular6, angular-service-worker

I have followed this link for integration
https://medium.com/@a.adendrata/push-notifications-with-angular-6-firebase-cloud-massaging-dbfb5fbc0eeb

Here is firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in the
// messagingSenderId.
firebase.initializeApp({
  'messagingSenderId': '426004542538'
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Below is the environment file containing config info

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBvhz9Ml0Nd68SR8BRDxO10q6Hyptcnrjk",
    authDomain: "pushnotification-7fd02.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://pushnotification-7fd02.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "pushnotification-7fd02",
    storageBucket: "pushnotification-7fd02.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "426004542538"
  }
};
```

In postman I am using curl command for firebase

```
curl -X POST \
  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send \
  -H 'Authorization: key=AAAAYy_ZdEo:AP..........' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{ 
 "notification": {
  "title": "Hello World", 
  "body": "This is Message from Admin"
 },
 "to" : "fDFFOme2rEI:APA91bHnZGmt6ae5Jyuv2vI4WGBOg3XKMwtHpZIFAYa9slacU9Uvam_7OHSUs0k_TFwRqDZFwZ6WF2IqdOH7Mj1u6BSbunsPuYxeH1zFivnPYfQoZfxqbSkxQYDMDoO21xjUpSDWxqbp"
}'
```

The response of Postman is

```
{
    "multicast_id": 4927361125379832815,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1553764018334820%2fd9afcdf9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Though the postman response is 200 success, still data is not stored in firebase & I am not getting any push notifications . I am running ng serve --port 3000 which deploys on localhost:3000.

Answer (score 2):

please change your **firebase-messaging-sw.js** to this I think then it will be run

```
     importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-app.js');
     importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.9.0/firebase-messaging.js');
      var config = {
       apiKey: ..... ,
       authDomain: .....,
       databaseURL: .....,
       projectId: .....,
       storageBucket: .....,
       messagingSenderId: .....
          };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
      const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

> or if you want to customize notification display then use this as well after above code

```
       messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
       const title = payload.data.title;
        const option = {              
          body: payload.data.message 
          icon: 'Path' 
          }  
             return self.registration.showNotification(title,option);
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution you need to change the version of firebase from 3.0.0 to 7.0.0, inside the file
importScripts ('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts ('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-messaging.js');

the file is firebase-messaging-sw.js

Answer (score 0):

Change the package version of fire and firebase to "@angular/fire": "^5.0.0" and "firebase": "^5.5.0". It will solve the issue.